# how i can join this too meshes and put them in the right place?

Tags: mesh

i been trying to join these to together in the exact join but i cant do it, is there at least a way to make those joins be in the exact place to match the meshes?[image]

Comment: Are you trying to merge them into a single mesh or are you trying to attach the arm(?) to the torso for animation? You can use the "Child Of" object constraint to make the arm follow the torso

Comment: Are these two armatures wouldn't the arm rig just be apart of the rest of the body rig?